# AirBnB Linter multiple currying in same line making it too long

Tags: eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I seem to have run into an AirBnB linting paradox.

I have the following line:

```
const pagePromiseGenerator = (graphql, createPage) => (gqlNodeName, pageComponent) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

which is over 100 characters long. So I can convert it to:

```
const pagePromiseGenerator = (graphql, createPage) => {
  return (gqlNodeName, pageComponent) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

But that violates the AirBnB arrow body style rule. Should I just disable linting for this line, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can satisfy both rules. You'll see in the [implicit-arrow-linebreak docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/implicit-arrow-linebreak) that you can wrap an implicit return in parentheses:

```
const pagePromiseGenerator = (graphql, createPage) => (
  (gqlNodeName, pageComponent) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // some code here
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const pagePromiseGenerator = (graphql, createPage) =>
  (gqlNodeName, pageComponent) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

Comment: When I try that, the linter gives me `[eslint] Expected no linebreak before this expression. (implicit-arrow-linebreak)`

Comment: Then, I guess you should disable it. Your argument names are long enough to be over 100 characters long, but judging by your code they need to be in order to be clear what is going on...